# ¿Como hago para instalar MySQL correctamente en manjaro/Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, manjaro

Hola a la hora de instalar mariadb me sale un error que dice que no se puede conectar al servidor.

Cuando escribo el comando: sudo systemctl start mariadb
Me aparece el error que esta abajo.

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xeu mariadb.service" for details.
```

Cuando verifico el status me sale todo esto.

```
sudo systemctl status mariadb
× mariadb.service - MariaDB 11.0.2 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-07-13 19:54:13 -03; 1min 16s ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 3042 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exite>
    Process: 3043 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/b>
    Process: 3069 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (>
   Main PID: 3069 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"
        CPU: 187ms

jul 13 19:54:13 chinaskidev mariadbd[3069]: 2023-07-13 19:54:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
jul 13 19:54:13 chinaskidev mariadbd[3069]: 2023-07-13 19:54:13 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function>
jul 13 19:54:13 chinaskidev mariadbd[3069]: 2023-07-13 19:54:13 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration >
jul 13 19:54:13 chinaskidev mariadbd[3069]: 2023-07-13 19:54:13 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is dis>
jul 13 19:54:13 chinaskidev mariadbd[3069]: 2023-07-13 19:54:13 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin t>
jul 13 19:54:13 chinaskidev mariadbd[3069]: 2023-07-13 19:54:13 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage e>
jul 13 19:54:13 chinaskidev mariadbd[3069]: 2023-07-13 19:54:13 0 [ERROR] Aborting
jul 13 19:54:13 chinaskidev systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAI>
jul 13 19:54:13 chinaskidev systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jul 13 19:54:13 chinaskidev systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 11.0.2 database server.
```

ALGUIEN PUEDE AYUDARME COMO INSTALARLO BIEN? gracias...

Intento instalar mysql en manjaro linux, y espero que me ayuden...

Comment: La instalación es simple ¿seguiste las [instrucciones](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-install-apache-mariadb-mysql-php-lamp/13000)?

Comment: Lo hice, pero sale el error que he comentado arriba.

Comment: Aunque MariaDB es un fork de MySQL, sigue siendo acerca de MariaDB tu pregunta :)

Answer (score 1):

He resuelto mi problema, con los siguientes pasos:

```
~]$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

> Job for **`mariadb.service`** failed because the control process exited with error code.
> See **`"systemctl status mariadb.service"`** and **`"journalctl -xeu mariadb.service"`** for details.

Va a observar  el error anterior cuando intentes iniciar los servicios de `MariaDB` en su sistema ejecutando los comandos que se detallan a continuación:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mariadb.service
$ sudo systemctl status mariadb.service
```

**¿Como solucionarlo?**

Para resolver el problema mencionado anteriormente, debe implementar algún conjunto de comandos en el terminal.

Yo, navegué en los directorios de datos y enumeré todos los archivos utilizando los siguientes comandos

> **NOTA**: Usé `sudo su` para entrar, pero pueda que a usted le funcione tal como esta escrito abajo.

```
$ cd / var / lib / mysql
$ ls
```

**2. Eliminar todos los datos de los directorios**

```
$ rm -r *
```

**3. Nuevamente inicializa el directorio de la base de datos** ejecutando el siguiente comando

```
$ mysql_install_db --user = mysql --basedir = / usr --datadir = / var / lib / mysql
```

**4. Inicie `mysqld`** ejecutando los siguientes comandos:

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

**5. Ahora, comience nuevamente el servicio `MariaDB` y `msql`**.

```
$ sudo systemctl start mysql.service
$ sudo systemctl start mariadb.service
```

Debe autenticar la contraseña de inicio de sesión del usuario. Ingrese la contraseña.

**6. Para obtener el estado del servicio**, ejecute el comando que figura a continuación:

```
$ sudo systemctl status mariadb.service
```

Y listo, tiene activado `mariadb`.

Buena Suerte.

Comment: Pon el contenido del enlace en tu respuesta. Piénsalo: si alguien llega a tener un problema similar más adelante, y el enlace cae, ¿cómo podrá saber si tu respuesta fue útil? Lee [answer].